# Change the billing email for notifications to a custom shipping one in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I changed checkout page for simpler process - I removed all billing fields and using shipping fields instead. So instead of *billing_email* I have *shipping_email*.

When customer makes order he didn't receive email notification because *billing_email* is not set.

Can you advice how to change customers notifications to be sent to *shipping_email* instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following custom hooked function, where I set the billing email from your custom shipping email. This way the notifications are sent to the correct email.

> You should need to check that `'_shipping_email'` is the correct metakey for the Shipping email custom checkout field… If not replace it by the right one.

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'set_billing_email_from_shipping_email', 50, 2 );
function set_billing_email_from_shipping_email( $order_id, $data ) {
    // Get customer shipping email
    $email = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_email', true );
    // Set billing email from shipping email
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', $email );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.